# Installing windows via VHD

Tags: iso-image, vhd

**Note: I am new to this site *and* new to how computer booting works**

I currently use a laptop with a HDD that is very slow. It is faster and more practical for me to run Windows 11 as a VHD off of a USB than use the internal hard disk. I am going to buy a new PC soon and I would like it to have all of the VHD’s data on it, but I want to boot from the internal hard drive, not the USB.

Can I somehow install Windows on the new PC using this VHD? I have tried searching for a way to convert it into an ISO windows installation, but have not found any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly the same as migrating any other Windows installation from one disk to another.

One method, using just built-in Windows tools, would be to use `dism /capture-image` to compress the entire system into a `.wim` archive, then extract to the new disk with `dism /apply-image`. You do need to create partitions on the new disk beforehand (using `diskpart`) and install the Windows Boot Manager after (using `bcdboot`), but it's an officially documented method (it's also how fresh Windows installation works under the hood).

(The advantage of this method versus various cloning software is that it doesn't need to have both disks accessible at once – you can use the old computer to create the .wim, move it over, apply it directly on the new computer without disassembling. This can be relevant if the source disk isn't physical, as some software refuse to work with attached VHDs.)

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "convert it into an ISO windows installation", but what's described above is actually almost the same thing as what the Windows installer does (except it unpacks a fresh system from Install.wim instead), and it is actually possible to make a custom "Windows install USB stick" that would use a custom image... just not worth the time for a single machine (they do it when they want to clone the same image into 2-3 digits worth of identical devices).